# How to execute an action upon clicking a hyperlink using :not() selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I want all the clicks on links to execute a certain action with the exception of `mailto` links. I have the following code that works as expected. It first attaches the function to all the links and then removes it from the `mailto` links:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">example.com</a>
<a href="mailto:someone@www.example.com">Someone</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a').on('click', function () {
        theAction();
    });
    $('a[href^="mailto"]').off('click');
</script>
```

I would like the same functionality but using the `:not()` selector as it looks more elegant. How would it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than attaching the event to each and every link, delegate it. This also makes it pretty easy to filter which do and don't fire it.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a:not([href^=mailto])', function(evt) {...
```

Comment: Good to know about delegation in Jquery.

Comment: @Clodoaldo - yeap, though be aware that it's a JS concept, not specifically jQuery. Perfectly do'able in native JS. Delegated events are more efficient where many elements are concerned, and have the advantage of automatically working on suitable elements that are inserted into the DOM even after the event is bound.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty straightforward:

```
$('a:not([href^="mailto"])').on(...);
```

or

```
$('a').not('[href^="mailto"]').on(...);
```

Have a look at the documentation:

- http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/not/

---

If you have many links on your page though, you should definitely go with *event delegation*, as Utkanos suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11648817/218196).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').not('a[href^="mailto"]').on('click', function () {
        theAction();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Felix solution is good, otherwise if other link are all absolute starting with `http/https` protocol try simply with

```
$('a[href^="http"]').on('click', function () {
    theAction();
});
```

Comment: Good. But no, there are relative links also just starting with something like `thepage?param=1`